# ¿ Cómo poner pestañas dentro de un Fragment?

Tags: java, android

MainActivity :

```
public class Presentacion extends AppCompatActivity

implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,FragmentFirst.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
FragmentSecond.OnFragmentInteractionListener,FragmentCalendario.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_calendario);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    boolean FragmentTransaction = false;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.PRIMERO) {

        Intent siguiente = new Intent(this, PrimerCuatrimestre_1.class);
        startActivity(siguiente);

    } else if (id == R.id.SEGUNDO) {

        fragment = new FragmentSecond();
        FragmentTransaction = true;


    } else if (id == R.id.CALENDARIO) {

        fragment = new FragmentCalendario();
        FragmentTransaction = true;


    } else if (id == R.id.TERCERO) {

    } else if (id == R.id.CUARTO) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "AndroidSolved");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "si que funciona");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_puntuar) {

    }

    if (FragmentTransaction) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction (Uri uri){
}

}
```

Fragment donde quiero ver las pestañas:

```
public class FragmentFirst extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FragmentFirst() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_second, container, false);


}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}




/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}


}
```

¿Cómo poner `tabs`(pestañas) dentro de este `fragment` ?

Comment: Revisa [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469877/adding-tab-inside-fragment-in-android)

Comment: Lo he seguido pero me sale error.... puedes ayudarme por favor con otra solución o revisando su mensaje qué está mal?

Answer (score 1):

Primero añade esta libreria

> ```
> compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
> ```

Despues Crea una Clase aparte que se llame PagerAdapter y cambia en cada lugar que dice fragment1, fragment2 y fragment3 por el nombre de tus fragments, puedes poner menos o mas, los que vos quieras.

> ```
> class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
> ```

```
private final String[] TITLES = {"Fragment1", "Fragment2", "Fragment3"};

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}



public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}


public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:

            return new fragment1;
        case 1:

            return new fragment2;
        case 2:
            return new fragment3;
    }

    return null;
}
```

}